# Conditional Iteration with JSON object in python to send email

Tags: python, json

Dear Fellow Python Developers,
I've been trying to write a script that will send an email from the JSON object as mentioned below.

Use case:
The script checks the of the value of the Description key and sends the email to the email address key.It should run throughout the whole JSON and send the emails accordingly.

The content in the description value should be included in the message body.
And it should only send if the description starts with 
"xxx". if it doesn't start with xxx it shouldn't send the email.

I am facing issues with iterations as I am only able to make it send the email of one JSON object.

I new code modification would be appreciated.

```
import json
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import json
import sys
import smtplib
from smtplib import SMTPException

#reading the report that has been generated in SolvIT as Json Object
reportJson = [
            {
             "RequestID":"23"
             "Name":"Bob"
             "email address":"a@b.com"
             "Description":"Please go to point M"
             "Position":"Manager"
            }

            {
             "RequestID":"23"
             "Name":"Bob"
             "email address":"c@g.com"
             "Description":"Please go to point 5"
             "Position":"Manager"
            }

            {
             "RequestID":"23"
             "Name":"Bob"
             "email address":"j@v.com"
             "Description":"Please go to point 1"
             "Position":"Manager"
            }

            {
             "RequestID":"23"
             "Name":"Bob"
             "email address":"i@c.com"
             "Description":"xxxPlease go to point 18"
             "Position":"Manager"
            }

            {
             "RequestID":"23"
             "Name":"Bob"
             "email address":"h@b.com"
             "Description":"Please go to point 20"
             "Position":"Manager"
            }

            {
             "RequestID":"23"
             "Name":"Bob"
             "email address":"f@q.com"
             "Description":"Please go to point 23"
             "Position":"Manager"
            }

            {
             "RequestID":"23"
             "Name":"Bob"
             "email address":"y@mail.com"
             "Description":"xxxPlease go to point 12"
             "Position":"Manager"
            }

            {
             "RequestID":"23"
             "Name":"Bob"
             "email address":"r@mail.com"
             "Description":"Please go to point 123"
             "Position":"Manager"
            }

            {
             "RequestID":"23"
             "Name":"Bob"
             "email address":"a@mail.com"
             "Description":"xxxPlease go to point 98"
             "Position":"Manager"
            }


         ]



#Reading the Request JSON 
json_data=open(reportJson).read()
data = json.loads(json_data)

#the 4th row in the report
for dObj in data:
    e_mail=dObj['email address']

#the 5th row in the report
for dObj1 in data:
    work_log=dObj1['Description']

#if work_log[:2]=:xxx:
#   send mail           I want to send email only if the description starts  
# with xxx, and if it doesn't start with xxx it should send an email

#custom message that is to be sent out
message = """From: Seruken <server2@gmail.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
Subject: A task in the ticket you created has been resolved

This email sent for the request created with the Subject

""" + " " + work_log

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
   smtpObj.ehlo()
   smtpObj.starttls()
   smtpObj.login('server2@gmail.com', 'password')
   smtpObj.sendmail('server2@gmail.com', e_mail, message)         
   print ("Successfully sent email")

except SMTPException as err:
   print ("Error: unable to send email", err)
```

Comment: How about `if work_log.startswith('xxx')`?

Comment: You should learn how loops work... There should be one single loop here.

Comment: Your Example `reportJson` is neither valid `json` nor a valid Python Object.

Comment: @stovfl Its a valid Json object, i just didnt put the commas in the code but the format is {
             "RequestID":"23",
             "Name":"Bob",
             "email address":"j@v.com",
             "Description":"Please go to point 1",
             "Position":"Manager"
            }

Answer (score 0):

```
# read your report file
with open("report.json") as report_file:
    data = json.load(report_file)

for obj in data:
    # get description field
    description = obj['Description']
    # check if it started with 'xxx'
    if description.startswith('xxx'):
        email = obj['email address']
        # send email logic
```

Comment: When i use that piece of code below it says the email isn't defined i believe its because its nested
    `if description.startswith('xxx'):`

               `email = obj['email address']`